# What is the algorithm that Stack Overflow uses to handle the insertion of duplicate posts?

Tags: duplicates

I want to know the algorithm that Stack Overflow uses to handle the insertion of duplicate posts.
This can be useful for auto-bug filing process.

Comment: Well, do you know anything about stackoverflow? For example the stuff you read on duplicate questions about WHO CLOSES IT. No algo - it is users closing doubles.